# Track restarts, shuts down, power up and power down

Tags: android

can we get notification if user restarts, shuts down, power up or down the device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ajay,

The two Broadcast Actions you are most likely interested in are:

- [`ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED):  This is broadcast once, after the system has finished booting.
- [`ACTION_SHUTDOWN`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN): Device is shutting down. This is broadcast when the device is being shut down (completely turned off, not sleeping).

Please keep in mind to receive `ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETE` you must have the [`RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED) permission in your AndroidManifest.xml